# Recompiling a revised r package

Tags: r, package, recompile

Disclaimer: I am not a coder and have only a very limited working understanding of r, so I apologise if my question is completely feeble.

I was using the r package "pegas" (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pegas/pegas.pdf) and came across some errors with some of the functions, which the package developer kindly fixed after I brought them to his attention. He provided the fixes on Github here: https://github.com/emmanuelparadis/pegas/commit/4ce1b3396a6e90f3acf76e44469b107a3a1923da

He said that I need to recompile the whole package with the new fixes.

The problem is, is that I have absolutely no idea how to do this. In my naivety, I tried install.packages("pegas", lib="~/Documents/", dependencies = "Depends"), thinking that I could then open the file and replace the necessary .R files, but this didn't work (I couldn't see any files in the library folder that resembled the .R files I need to update). 
I've done some searches on Google and here, but to be honest I just can't find something this specific that has been helpful. I am not even sure that I'm getting the files off Github correctly - I assume I do View < Raw < and then copy and paste the text into a text editor and save in the necessary format (i.e. .R).

I'm using a Mac and r Studio (r V. 3.2.4).

Comment: `devtools::install_github("emmanuelparadis/pegas")`

Comment: A bit more to previous comment; see [R Packages](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/) by Hadley; particularly the GitHub section. If the author has made the changes in the master then @AlexW code will work fine; otherwise you need to specificy the branch as the `reference` parameter.

Comment: Thanks. I tried Alex's suggestion, but got the following error: "Does not appear to be an R package (no DESCRIPTION). Not sure why it says that as there clearly is a description on that page.

Comment: As I predicted. "Does not appear to be an R package (no DESCRIPTION)". Added a couple of tags and maybe someone will construct a tutorial on using Rstudio for package modifications using its features suited for version control.

Comment: @42- Ok, thanks. I guess I'll try track someone down then!

Comment: Wait! If you had followed the link on the pdf you would have found directions for installing from github: `library(devtools);
install_github("emmanuelparadis/pegas/pegas") `   It does have a large number of dependencies, however it then fails its final loading tests with `Symbol not found: ___addtf3`

Comment: @42- Yeah, ok I got an error about a directory not being found. I've found some previous posts about that on here, so I'll have a look at those. Thanks, again